# How to create a virtual printer and redirect the file to an application server

Tags: ruby, printing, virtual, driver, port

I've been for some days now, investigating on how to create a Virtual printer driver, a port monitor, and file redirect to an application server, via a remote JSON service.

I've stumbled upon the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx), as well as a [guide](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~henrik/GSPSprinter/GSPSprinter.html) to build a virtual printer using GhostScript. I actually followed this guide, but in the end didn't manage to get the test page printed (the last step), and don't actually know if i should keep trying.

I find it impressive that so many people have already asked this or similar questions, but none has written a guide on how to really do it, and that is what i intend to appeal for with this post. All i find is commercial drivers, and people trying to make money out of a driver. I do also intend to use this on a commercial service, but its all about the end value of service, and not the pieces it uses to run.

I appeal now to the community, so that if anyone might already have solved this problem, or just part of it, or wants to give it a try so that he/she may share. I will keep my research going, and intend to share it along the way...but i'm feeling like have to reinvent the wheel here..

I wonder if we can only use c or vb to do this...Would it be plausible to do it with ruby?

Comment: @Klaus, you say it has nothing to do with ruby, and yet i ask in the post "Would it be plausible to do it with ruby"...so i guess there is ruby to it, or am i wrong?

Comment: i have the same problem and i say what i doing here


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094003/generating-xps-document-with-passthrough-xps-driver